# How can I do this css code using sass

Tags: saas

The CSS code is:

```
.parent {display: block;}
.parent .child {color: #fff;}
.parent:hover .child {color: #000;}
```

I've tried this sass code, but is failed.

```
.parent {
  display: block;
  .child {
    color: #fff;
  }
  @at-root #{&}:hover & {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
.parent {
  display: block;
  .child {
    color: #fff;
  }
  &:hover .child {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

You can use tools like [css 2 sass converter tool](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) to convert your css.